# Does CPU time slicing work on Node.js with or without worker thread if there's only 1 cpu core?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, cpu

Since Node.js 10.5, they introduced the new worker thread which makes Node.js a multi-thread environment.

Previously, with only one thread on Node.js, there's no cpu time slicing happening because of the event driven nature (If I understand correctly).

So now multiple threads on Node with with one physical cpu core, how do they share the cpu? is it the OS scheduler schedule time for each thread to run for various amount of time or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worker threads are advertised as

> The Worker class represents an **independent** JavaScript execution **thread**.

So something like starting another NodeJS instance but within the same process and with a bare minimum of a communication channel.

Worker threads in NodeJS mimick the Worker API in the modern browsers (not a coincidence, NodeJS is basically a browser without UI and with a few extra JS API) and in that context worker threads are really native threads, scheduled by the OS.

The description quoted above seems to imply that in NodeJS too, worker threads are implemented with native threads rather than with a scheduling managed by NodeJS.
The latter would be useless as this is *exactly* what the JS event loop coupled with async methods do.
So basically a worker thread is just another "instance" (context) of NodeJS run by another **native** thread in the same process.
Being a native thread, it is managed and scheduled by the OS. And just like you can run more than one program in a single CPU you can do that with threads (fun fact: in many OSes, *threads* are the only schedulable entities. Programs are just a group of thread with a common address space and other attributes).

As NodeJS is open source, it is easy to confirm this, see the [`Worker::StartThread`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_worker.cc#L575) and the [`Worker::Run`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_worker.cc#L231) functions.

The new thread will execute JS code just like the main one but it has been limited in the way it can interact with the environment (particularly the process itself).
This is in line with the JS approach to multithreading where it is more of "two or more message loops" than real multithreading (where threads are free to interact with each other with all the implication at the architectural level).